# WCF/Silverlight/SQL DB Caching Strategies

Tags: wcf, silverlight, caching

Ok, I have a pretty complex silverlight app that gets its data from a WCF service (asp.net hosted service layer) which in turn calls into a data layer that calls stored procedures in a SQL 2005 DB to extract the needed data.  So the round trip goes like this:

Silverlight App --> WCF Service --> Data Layer --> DB --> Data Layer --> WCF Service transforms Data Entity into corresponding DTO (Data Transfer Object) or List<> thereof --> Silverlight App

Much of the data is highly relational (so it needs to exist in the DB), but it will change infrequently.  It seems that I have several choices of locations to cache this "semi-constant" data:

1. I can cache it in the data layer.  My data layer is already set up to use the SQLDependency class and cache the results from a stored procedure call.  I think that this is or can be an application level cache.
2. I can cache the resulting DTO in an application level (or session level depending on the call) cache within the WCF service itself.
   2(a) I could even take this a step further by serializing the XML for the resulting DTO(s) into a file on the WCF service side so that I could (a) check memory cache, then (b) check file cache and (c) hit the data layer
3. I could do something similar to 2(a) with isolated storage on the client side within the SL app.  I could serialize the data to the local isolated storage with a hash (or a moddate or something) and then just make a call to check that.

One more thing to add:  I am hosting this WCF service in IIS7 with dynamic compression turned on so that the (often very large and easily compressed) XML response gets gzip-ed.  Ideally, it would seem, I would like IIS to cache this gzip-ed result to avoid all the extra processing.  I think that it may do this already but I am not sure.

I am pretty sure that the final answer to this is some flavor of "it depends", but I would love to hear how others are approaching this.  A good tactical recipe of Do X, Test Performance with tool Y, the do Z if needed would be great to have.

A few links (I will add to this as I research this):

[WCF Caching Approach](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2007/08/10/architecture-wcf-services-and-caching.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have data that are user that will change quite rarely and need fast response, going for a custom mechanism bases on local storage is a great advantage quite faster than having to wait for a server roundtrip.

Dino Sposito published an interesting article about local storage and caching on MSDN Magazine there you can find as well an approach to catch assemblies (imagine just loading the minimum package required and just go loadin the rest of assemblies in background, ... performance rocket, more complexity on your code :)).

As you said is matter to go putting in a balance and decide.

HTH
  Braulio

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be this:

1. Determine if there is actually a problem with performance (isn't it alreade acceptable to my users?)
2. Measure the performance at each teir (how long does it take the database to come up with data? how long does it take the service to respond with data? how much time does it take from the service to the client?)
3. Based on the measurements I would then determine where to do my caching. Remember that, the closer to your data storage you do caching, the easier it is, but the closer to the client you do caching, the better the performance gain (usually).

Also remember that caching should not be the first thing to do to improve performance. You should also look into other performance gains as well. Are the stored procedures slow? Is there a lot of overhead in the WCF messages? Is there some inefficient processing in the service? Do I realy need all that data in one message?

HTH, 
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

I think #2 is your best bet for maintainability and architecture.  IIS provides caching, why not use it?

You don't want to have to reference System.Web from a data layer.  Client side is not the best option either, because you'd have to write a bunch of additional code to keep the data synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Is System.Web caching even available to WCF when it's not running in ASP.NET compatible mode? Probably best not to depend on it and write your own.

On the other hand, look into Microsoft's Velocity project, which looks like it will produce a very interesting caching technology not dependant on ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

We just recently implemented #3, the client-side caching using Isolated Storage.

In our app we have lot of drop downs and custom fields which the app used to get from the server every time it loads. Moving these data to IS really helped. The app now makes a call to check if there were any changes on the server, and if not - loads the data from the IS, otherwise ( which is pretty rare ) refreshes IS.

That eliminated a lot of WCF calls and data transfers, the SL pages' loading time is shorter, and the app in general became more scalable because of the reduced network traffic and db access.

Yes, there are some coding involved, but the benefits for the end users are essential.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

If you use RIA Services, then a simple approach is to have two separate edmx definitions. One for cached entities, one for transactional ones.

One domain context can reference the entities on another domaincontext via AddReference [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.domaincontext.addreference%28VS.91%29.aspx).

The cached entities could be loaded immediately after user has authenticated. For simplicity, transactional data should not load until cached entities have loaded.

Depending on the size of the cache, you may also wish to consider serializing these values to local storage.